Solving a trigonometric equation originating from law of sines
Often when using trigonometry, especially the sine law to solve geometry problems, I end up with the following equation
sin (x) sin(a) - sin (x+b) sin(c) = 0
However, I am often stuck as it is common that a, b, c are not special angles, e.g. a = 87°, b = 36°, c = 57°, which yields x = 57°. Is there any general methods or algorithms to solve these kinds of equations, by hand without using a calculator?

If it's a triangle and you already know two angles, the third angle is easy to find. Maybe you are overcomplicating things?

Well sometimes problems demand extensive geometry experience if one wish to solve it with elementary geometry.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vhklRWogzo&t=40s
It would be more general to solve it with trigonometry instead. Same applies for adventitious angles I think.

One approach to this would be to get an equation in terms either $\cos x$ or $\sin x$ and solve for cosine or sine.

For your specific question
$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin (x+b)}=\frac{\sin c}{\sin a}$$
Now $$a+b+c=180°\implies b+c=180°-a\implies \sin(b+c)=\sin(180°-a)=\sin a$$
This occurs due to the fact that $\sin x$ is positive for both first and second quadrants.
So
$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin (x+b)}=\frac{\sin c}{\sin(c+b)}$$
Hence by direct comparison, $x=c$
Extremely general approach for all $a,b,c$
$$\sin x\sin a=\sin (x+b)\sin c=\sin c\sin x\cos b+\cos x\sin b\sin c$$
Take $\sin x=u$.
$$u(\sin a-\sin c\cos b)=±\sqrt{1-u^2}\sin b\sin c$$
Square both sides
$$u^2(\sin a-\sin c \cos b)^2=\\(1-u^2)\sin^2b\sin^2c$$
$$\implies u^2(\sin^2 a+\sin^2 c\cos ^2 b-2\sin a\sin c \cos b +\sin b^2\sin^2 c)=\sin^2 b\sin^2 c$$
$$\implies u^2=\sin^2 x=\frac{\sin^2 b\sin^2 c}{\sin^2 a+\sin^2 c -2\sin a\sin c\cos b}$$
For a triangle, take $\sin a=\sin(b+c)$
